# Adding background image for Bootstrap list-group-item

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image, sprite

I have a sprite that I'm able to display per each `list-group-item`. However, I'm not able to individually style each image for .one, .two etc.

```
<div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item one">ONE</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item two">TWO</a>      
    <span class="list-group-item three">Share <span class="fb"><!--display FB icon--></span></span>
</div>
```

LESS:
Place text on left, align image on right side, works.
Now I want to style the individual images within each `.list-group-item`. As the images already repeat themselves, i just have to position them on the center of each anchor tag, and display certain pixel parts.

```
.list-group-item {
    width:100%
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align:left;
    background: url("Sprite.png") right no-repeat;
}
.one { top:0; left:-15px;}
```

I also tried adding images explicitly, like this:

```
<div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item one">ONE<span class="img"></span></a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item two">TWO<span class="img"></span></a>         
    <span class="list-group-item three">Follow <span class="fb"><!--display FB icon--></span>/span>
</div>
```

How can I get it to work?

Comment: Have you tried .list-group-item.one {top:0; left:-15px;} ?

Comment: Can you setup a demo of the current output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you want to achieve but I supposed that is something like this:

```css
.img{
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
    height: 44px;                /*Defines the height portion of the image we want to use*/
    background: url('http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_navsprites.gif') 0 0;
}
#one{
    width: 46px;                   /*Defines the width portion of the image we want to use*/
    background-position: 0 0;      /*Defines the background position (left 0px, top 0px)*/
}
#two{
    width: 43px;
    background-position: -47px 0;  /*Defines the background position 47px to the right (#one width 46px + 1px line divider)*/
}
#three{
    width: 43px;
    background-position: -91px 0;  /*Defines the background position 91px to the right (#home width 46px + 1px line divider + #two width 43px + 1px line divider )*/
}

.list-group-item{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="margin-bottom: 50px; text-align:center">
    Lets use this image:
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_navsprites.gif" alt="">
</div>

<div class="list-group"> 
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">ONE<span id="one"  class="img"></span></a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">TWO<span id="two" class="img"></span></a> 
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">THREE<span id="three" class="img"></span></a> 
</div>
```

So you have to move your background position to change the portion of the image you want to see.

[Here the full example](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp)

Anyway I really recommend you use a CSS Sprite Generator.